# CS1545 when moving from Visual Studio 2019 back to 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, csvhelper

I have a project which uses CsvHelper. This was developed on a computer with Visual Studio 2019 as a .Net Core 3.1 Console app.  I have moved the code to a computer that only has Visual Studio 2017.  The Framework version was changed back to 2.1 since that was all that is available without installing additional frameworks and shouldn't be an issue.  (I have also tried a .Net Framework console app targeting 4.6.1 with similar results).
My previously working code no longer compiles with a CS 1545 error (this is from one of my MANY test cases but it is the same error):

> Error CS1545  Property, indexer, or event 'CsvConfiguration.Delimiter'
> is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor
> methods 'CsvConfiguration.get_Delimiter()' or
> 'CsvConfiguration.set_Delimiter(?)'   ConsoleApp3 C:\Programming\ConsoleApp3\ConsoleApp3\Program.cs   16  Active

As noted above, the Framework version was set back to 2.1.  I have also tried changing the LangVersion (various values including 7.0, latest, and 7.3) in the *.csproj since the error specifically refers to the language.  I have also changed the Framework and LangVersion on the 2019 PC (to match the 2017 PC), and it compiles and runs fine.  The code was originally written against CsvHelper version 21.3.0 and I have reverted back to that version, flushed the Nuget cache, deleted the bin and obj folders, and cleaned the solution (and all of those before starting with a new console app).

I'm tagging CsvHelper because that is what I am using, but I honestly don't think that is the culprit.  I suspect there is an issue with Visual Studio / Nuget.  Searching for CS1545 does not yield anything promising.

[UPDATE] - It looks like changing back to version 19.0.0 fixes the issue, so something broke after that.  Maybe I was too willing to throw VS / Nuget under the bus.

Comment: perhaps you need to run a clean.

Comment: @DanielA.White - I have cleaned the solution.  I've also started a completely new console app project with no build having been done at all.  Before I even hit Build, I get the error.

Comment: how was `CsvConfiguration` built?

Comment: I think I found the issue.  According to the changelog, in version 20.0.0.  CsvConfiguration was changed to a record, and the properties were set to get; init;  I'm not knowledgeable enough about nuget packages and language versions, but those are not compatible with C# 7.3. which is the latest that is available on this PC.

Comment: so i'd use an older version of the package.

Comment: That's what I'm going to have to do.  I was looking at the changelog to see what I would miss.  Seems like a lot of bug fixes, but this code really only has to run once i.e. it is not a long term production system.